# iptables rules not working

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am at a loss to why my iptable rules are blocking access to `https://example.com:9700` despite `accept` rule being added

I start by clearing out everything

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

Then Dropping everything, adding exception for ssh and my 9700 port

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9700 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 9700 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The service works after the clear and stops working after the second set of rules.

Note that the rule for SSH works perfectly fine. I can reconnect to my server via SSH after the rule has been added

**DNS Issue**
Verified DNS is not working per one of the answers. However that does not explain why I still can not access it via ip address: `https://xx.xxx.xx.x:9700`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you resolve the name of example.com? If you block access to any name service, your machine won't be able to reach example.com - you would have to add the host example.com and his ip address in the /etc/hosts or add an iptables exception for your DNS.

As posted [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/dns-nslookup-and-iptables-79376/), an exception for DNS lookups would be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --source-port 53 -j ACCEPT
```

**EDIT**:

Since you outruled DNS problems, i looked deeper into your rule, and for my understanding of iptables, it cannot work.
You are allowing INPUT traffic (to your machine) on destination port 9700 (on your machine!), and OUTPUT traffic (from your machine to the outside) from your local port 9700.

What you want is the exact opposit (or am i wrong?): you want your machine to reach an external server on port 9700, and you want this server to be able to answer you.

So your last two rules should be:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9700 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This allows traffic that is starting from any port (because you cannot controll which port a protocol will use to for outgoing traffic) on your computer to any other machine on port 9700, and allows traffic from any other machine in the world to your computer IF the packets are part of a connection that was already established.

Comment: You are correct that my dns is not working, however the problem is still there when accessing it via ip address. Not that if I turn clear iptables, the ipaddress:port works perfectly fine

Comment: I added another possible solution you can test.

Comment: the new solution did fix the port issue and I was able to access the site using the ip address. I edit your post to show the correct dns mapping. Please edit it if you'd like before I accept it as an answer. It gets harder to edit afterwards.

Comment: I think all needed information is already there, if you think something is missing you are welcome to add it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9700 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 9700 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I'm supposing that the DNS server that resolves example.com IP address is not the same machine.

Also, I don't think that it is really a problem to set the OUTPUT chain's policy as ACCEPT. Try it out.

This set of rules works for me. It should work for you too.

Best regards!